# What if an variable in a multiple linear regression is insignificant and all five other variables are significant!

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

I am currently working on a paper, during the regression analysis of the variables I have one dependent variable and six independents. After the regression, five of the variables turned out to be significant, while one was insignificant.

Does it mean that all the regression must be changed? - because when one variable is insignificant all the regression is as well, or
Do I have to continue with other significant variables? - only mentioning that variable is insignificant and continuing with other variables?

Comment: please see my post here

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/571180/does-my-predictor-in-my-multiple-regression-have-too-many-variables/571186?noredirect=1#comment1055632_571186

it answers this exact question. Let me know if you would like anymore help (also, if you share your dataset, or a part of it, I would be happy to show you how to do model validation)

Comment: There are problems with your recommendations there @Andy.  Your approach of not trusting the overall pre-specified model and using things like AIC to choose a model will result in a biased (low) estimate of residual variance $\sigma^2$ which will damage all aspects of statistical inference.  The OP just needs to realize that "statistical significance" doesn't mean much, and that no damage (and a lot of good) comes from keeping "insignificant" variables in the model.  It also keeps the analyst from cherry picking.

Comment: @FrankHarrell thanks for the comment.  I simply meant to offer 4 different approaches to do model selection, and it's very likely possible that leaving a non-significant predictor in a linear model still improves the model based on all 4 tests I proposed. I agree that there is a large emphasis on p-values from linear model outputs, and other parameters (t values, f values) are also of high value

Comment: Thanks.  Typically the full model will predict better (doesn't waste information trying to select variables) and will be much better for computing standard errors.